# In Powershell on Windows 10, how can I remove / not display the long filename string on my prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

How do I remove all or part of the large filename string that appears before every prompt in powershell in Windows 10? I am using Gitshell with ConsoleZ and posh git. I've hunted through all their settings and found nothing.

I've circled in red in the image below the bit that I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the properties that control the prompt display: [PowerShell Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je52v.png). Basically all depends on a function called prompt which is  user modifiable.

> function prompt {
>   'PS ' + ($pwd -split '\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\')[-1] -join '\') + '> '
>   }

Using this function only displays the current dir without the path, but it seems you'll need to combine it with the posh git settings by defining a custom profile like the example in **profile.example.ps1** in the posh-git code

EDIT: Using this information (wich is not a solution by itself) komali_2 was able to find the following solution:

> DrNoone's answer provides a lot of great background to why this works,
>   and I highly recommend reading through his material.
>
> In order to achieve my question, do the following:
>
> 1. Open up the profile.example.ps1 file in the posh-git install directory in a text editor.
> 2. Edit it to look like below:
>
> .
>
> ```
> Push-Location (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent)
>
> # Load posh-git module from current directory
> Import-Module .\posh-git
>
> # If module is installed in a default location ($env:PSModulePath),
> # use this instead (see about_Modules for more information):
> # Import-Module posh-git
>
>
> # Set up a simple prompt, adding the git prompt parts inside git repos
> function global:prompt {
>     $realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE
>
>     Write-Host(($pwd -split '\\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\\')[-1] -join '\')) -nonewline
>
>     Write-VcsStatus
>
>     $global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
>     return "> "
> }
>
> Pop-Location
>
> Start-SshAgent -Quiet
> ```
>
> This will result in your prompt looking like:
>
> [image]

Comment: I believe you're right about the posh-git customising, because when I added `function prompt { 
'PS ' + ($pwd -split '\\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\\')[-1] -join '\') + '> '
}
` directly to my profile.ps1, it no longer displays posh-git stuff.

Comment: I've added the process in an answer below. I hate doing that because your answer was what guided me to find the full answer, so if within 48 hours you add the steps I wrote out below to your answer I will happily accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

DrNoone's answer provides a lot of great background to why this works, and I highly recommend reading through his material.

In order to achieve my question, do the following:

1. Open up the profile.example.ps1 file in the posh-git install directory in a text editor.
2. Edit it to look like below:

.

```
Push-Location (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent)

# Load posh-git module from current directory
Import-Module .\posh-git

# If module is installed in a default location ($env:PSModulePath),
# use this instead (see about_Modules for more information):
# Import-Module posh-git


# Set up a simple prompt, adding the git prompt parts inside git repos
function global:prompt {
    $realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE

    Write-Host(($pwd -split '\\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\\')[-1] -join '\')) -nonewline

    Write-VcsStatus

    $global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
    return "> "
}

Pop-Location

Start-SshAgent -Quiet
```

This will result in your prompt looking like:

[image]

Comment: Is it somehow possible to achieve this without the installation of Posh-Git or any other third party software?

Comment: just define a `function prompt` in your normal PowerShell profile.

Comment: @nixda Use DrNoone's code `function prompt { 'PS ' + ($pwd -split '\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\')[-1] -join '\') + '> ' }` except literally just paste it into your profile.ps1 file. See DrNoone's first link on more information on where to find that file, there are several locations it can be.

Comment: @komali_2 His first link is a picture

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but did you figure it out?